# Can Speaker Recognition API recognise if a voice is live or recorded?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I want to know if someone has a recording of someone else's voice, can they use that recording with Speaker Recognition API to pretend they are that person. I.e. can Speak Recognition API recognise if a voice is live or recorded?

Comment: I very much doubt it can tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I can't provide an answer specific to the Microsoft technology you mentioned, but I can make a few general remarks that might hold true nevertheless:

First, any technical system can only "listen" to a human voice through... a recording, since it doesn't have ears. So the real question is, can it distinguish between a live recording of a human voice and a pre-recorded recording of a human voice? Basically, that's something akin to a reversed [Turing test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) where the machine tries to determine whether it's dealing with a machine, or a human.

Even if we ignore this very fundamental issue for a moment, I suspect that distinguishing between "live talk" and a "recording" might be difficult for any AI. This is easy for humans among other things because...

- the reverb characteristics of what you hear often do not match the place that you are in; or
- the sound isn't 3D enough; or
- sound fidelity does not match what it should typically be for the sound transmission medium.

For those reasons distinguishing live & playback becomes harder over telecom (ever confused an answering machine with a real human?), but

- if you know the person and/or the place they are supposedly in (typical background sounds) it's still easily possible.

An AI can't use these kinds of implicit knowledge of a person & their places.

One thing that an AI *could* do just like humans is try to interrupt the other party and see whether the other party stops talking to listen. If the other party doesn't react at all, it's perhaps a recording (the answering machine problem again). Though that's clearly not a foolproof test. We're back to in reverse Turing test waters.

P.S. if, in the course of trying to answer this question, you invent an acoustic, reversed version of [ELIZA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) that tries to figure out whether her patient is human or not, I'm offering myself as a test subject. That would be a wickedly fun experiment.

Answer (score 0):

yes, of course we can do it by Speaker Recognition API . i have done it already and its working fine . i used js to capture the live audio stream then send it to the speaker api with the help of custom webapi which i coded .

mainly it consist of 3 steps,

1. create a profile - which returns a unique profile ID.
2. Entroll - entroll / upload the audio to the profile ID , it stores your voice 
            sample permanently.
3. verify- verify your current audio with the samples you have saved before .

this is the main concept of the Speaker Recognition API , if you forward to look at the implementation i can help you .

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/563309b7778daf06340c9652

Comment: in which language you have accomplished the said task?

Comment: How did you accomplish the said task?

Comment: @Ramseen Ramsi, I am trying to do some what similar to what you have explained for Speaker Recognition API. Is it possible for you to share the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Speaker Recognition API currently does not differentiate between a live and a recorded audio, but the team is looking into that.